# PS4 Game Share technical issues

Tags: ps4

So my older step brother has quite the management issue with my ps4 , we share this as a family but he likes to put it as his. He has gameshared the game overwatch and has got it from someone else. I have two questions. 1 is it possible to game share a game share , and 2 if it’s possible if he gameshares that game and he is the primary user, is the game locked for all the other users on that ps4?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to "Share Play" as the mechanism for your brother sharing a game, then what you're asking is not possible.

"Share Play" means you're streaming the game of another persons console. You can only play the game while both players are online, and the game is not installed on your own console. So in short, you cannot re-share a "Share Play" game.

If you brother is sharing the game by using the primary account of another person (by effectively knowing their PSN login details), then again the game can only be used on 2 consoles - the Primary one (in this case your console), and the friend's console (which originally purchased the game). You can share it with another person, but it means you can no longer play it (since the new person will become the primary account user). This process also invoiced [activating and deactivate the consoles as "Primary"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjRaCp_CoOo).